# PHP include does not show the full file

Tags: php, html, include

I am trying to include an html "piece".  The piece is simply a header with a comment at the top:

```
<!--
Flex Web Core v2.0.2
Available in Perforce //FlexWeb/v2.0.2
Date: 2016-04-07T16:30:29
-->

<header class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header__inner"><a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    </div>
</header>
```

this file is called `header-basic.html`.

in my `index.php` file I have this line to include the `header-basic.html`

```
 <?PHP include 'node_modules/flexwebcore/dist/html/blocks/header-basic.html'; ?>
```

The basic-header html does not show up (whether it's a .php or .html file being included).  When I inspect the code, I can see the comment of the header-basic file, but I do not see the HTML being included.  Any ideas?

Here's where it's included:

```
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <!-- Place Header Here -->
        <?PHP include 'node_modules/flexwebcore/dist/html/blocks/header-basic.html'; ?>
        <main class="page-main">
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT** So, I believe I've found that only the header and footer files are not showing up.  Is there a problem with including `<header>` and `<footer>` tags?  The location that they are being included into are valid.

Comment: How exactly do you inspect resulting code? Your browser's fancy DOM pane will not show actual source code, you have to use the *View Source* feature. (BTW, if your PHP file doesn't have PHP code I wouldn't call it PHP.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm inspecting the code with Chrome's element inspector.  It's not showing up, but I'm able to traverse containers to where the this header SHOULD be.  All I see is the comment.  When I view page source, I see the HTML, but it's not showing up at all on the page.  Also, I agree with you that it's not a php page without php, I was testing to see if the `include` function NEEDED php.

Comment: Then it's clear: you've injected a `<header>` tag somewhere where it's not allowed. I suggest you verify your page with an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and fix invalid markup.

Comment: `but it's not showing up at all on the page.` - are you styling the header element with css?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Can you explain where a header would not be allowed? It's inside the body, I don't know any other exceptions to the header rule.  HTML Validator validates just fine

Comment: @NickR, I can't even "see" the header in the code, let alone see if it's available to style.  The header is certainly not styled to be hidden.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Also, the way I have been doing it before was having jQuery inject a javascript variable version of the header.  The HTML is exactly the same, and it works and looks fine.  The only difference is that I made it a javascript variable, rather than including another file.

Comment: Example for forbidden locations: `<header></header><!DOCTYPE HTML>`, `</head><header></header><body>`, `<input type="text" name="foo" <header></header>>`...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Thank you for the examples.  The code is sound and valid

Comment: ... because W3C validator says so?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: Do you see the header when you do View Source?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Because YOUR examples say so.  If you'd like to be helpful, please continue to be helpful.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, I can see it when I view page source

Comment: Is the page with the problem accessible from the Internet? What's the URL?

Comment: @Barmar http://cleanercoding.com/gd-pagebuilder-v1.0/?page_id=2

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for the downvote :) because you're better than this.

Comment: Sorry for annoying you suggesting tools to do the job. The [W3C also thinkgs your HTML is not valid](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fcleanercoding.com%2Fgd-pagebuilder-v1.0%2F%3Fpage_id%3D2) but how are they to contradict you?

Comment: You're welcome. A question where the OP actively refuses to go through diagnose steps and feels insulted for the mere suggestion doesn't deserve less.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, So now you trust w3c validation?  I JUST added the in-page style to protect the company just a bit.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I did EVERYTHING you said.  And nothing worked.  Not sure why you're "holier than thou".  Your suggestions seem, fine.  Your tone is improper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `js/global.js` you have a Javascript function that's removing the `<header>` element:

```
function page_type_change(page_type) {
    $('header').remove();
    $('footer').remove();
    $('.page-container').removeClass('page-container--footer-full');
    //$('.page-container').prepend(getHeader(page_type));
    $('body').append(getFooter(page_type));
    if(page_type === "pre" || page_type === "post"){
        $('.page-container').addClass('page-container--footer-full');
    } else {
        $('.page-container').removeClass('page-container--footer-full');
    }
}
```

You need to fix this function or your HTML to match what you want.

Comment: Yes! There's my idiocy! I read through that code so many times because that's where I originally included the header (`getHeader()`).  Great job sleuthing! Thank you!  I'm building a page-builder from scratch and I need everything to function at a click of a button...

Answer (score 1):

instead try to do require_once and see what happens.. it maybe because of comments.. try to remove the comments and give it a try... you can put the comments to the master file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've just tried both, but to no avail.

Comment: can you also just small case the <?PHP